# Google App Engine users lib stopped working

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Hello So I have a working app for my school using GAE.

now untill a few days ago it all worked just fine, however when i tried to log it again , suddently i get "Connection Failure" meaning the user from current user in the android app returned None.

```
class AddUser(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def action(self):
        #userID          = self.request.get('user_id') # get it from mobile phone user.user_id()
        user = users.get_current_user()

        #user = 1
        if not user:
            status = Status(-1, 'Connection failure')
            self.response.write(status.to_JSON())
            return
        userID = user.user_id()
        query = ndb.gql("""SELECT * FROM UserProfile WHERE user_id=:u""" ,u=userID)

        for q in query:
            status = Status(0, str(userID))
            self.response.write(status.to_JSON())
            return

        name = self.request.get('user_name')
        icon = self.request.get('user_icon')
        passw = self.request.get('user_password')
        emailP = user.email()
        newUser = UserProfile(user_id = userID,
                              user_name = name,
                              password = passw,
                              email = emailP)

        if icon != '':
            newUser.profile_picture = str(icon)
        newUser.put()

        status = Status(1, str(userID))
        self.response.write(status.to_JSON())
        return

    def post(self):
        self.get()
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(json.dumps(self.action(), indent=4))
```

it fails in "not user", I've debugged it in android and i defintally see that i'm looged to my gmail account..

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As I thought the problem is my auth token that was expired.
so all i did was change the gmail i've logged my app and it worked :)